# Crash-sound on viber notification Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, 18.04, notification, viber

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and i installed Viber for linux. Everything's working fine, but when i got a new message for example, the notification sound is not clean and seems like a "crash" and didn't find a way to disable the sound of viber notifications.

Can someone help please? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Perform the following steps:

<kbd>Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Sound</kbd> → <kbd>Sound effects</kbd>

and turn off **`Alert volume`**?.

If you just want to turn off the sound for one application you could also go to:

<kbd>Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Notifications</kbd>

and select your application and turn off **`Sound alerts`**.

Comment: @zx485 ans Ruben: Please review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1063636/revisions) and also review the «editing help ](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits/answers in the future...  **;-)**  Also: Do, or Do not; there is no try. **And +1**

Comment: I wanted a solution for the problem, turning off the sound is just hiding the problem... That's what i already did until now waiting for a better solution, but thank you for your help